# Pass multiple checkbox values to dropdown lists in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox with 5 options. Only two of these can be selected. What I am trying to do is pass the value checked to a dropdown list. Since two checkboxes can be selected, I would like their values to be passed to two dropdown lists. Here's what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="adventure" id="adventure"/><label for="adventure">Adventure</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="attraction" id="attraction"/><label for="attraction">Attraction</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="culture" id="culture"/><label for="culture">Culture</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="leisure" id="leisure"/><label for="leisure">Leisure</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="nature" id="nature"/><label for="nature">Nature</label>

<select id="list2">
<option value="adventure">Adventure</option>
<option value="attraction">Attractions</option>
<option value="culture">Culture</option>
<option value="leisure">Leisure</option>
<option value="nature">Nature</option>
</select>

<select id="list1">
<option value="adventure">Adventure</option>
<option value="attraction">Attractions</option>
<option value="culture">Culture</option>
<option value="leisure">Leisure</option>
<option value="nature">Nature</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="adventure"){
        $("#list1").val("adventure");
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="attraction"){
        $("#list2").val("attraction");
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="culture"){
        $(".cultureInterests").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="leisure"){
        $(".leisureInterests").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="nature"){
        $(".natureInterests").toggle();
    }
});
```

As you can see, this method is faulty as the order of selecting a checkbox is beyond my control and I won't be able to tell where to pass the value. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EXAMPLE**

> Here's a JSFiddle of what I am trying to achieve. Notice how the dropdown lists value change when you click on Adventure or Attractions.
>   http://jsfiddle.net/ajitks/3hdbgw79/

Thank you so much!

Comment: Its quite confusing.. Could you put up a demo?

Comment: Where are these classes `cultureInterests`, `leisureInterests`, `natureInterests` in the HTML.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - Thanks for replying. Hope this helps - http://jsfiddle.net/ajitks/3hdbgw79/

Comment: @Alorika those classes are for different elements. I am not using them for now. hope this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajitks/3hdbgw79/) should help. Thanks!

Comment: So what you want is whichever the 2 option is selected that has to be reflected in dropdown list?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes. Whichever two options that are checked should show up on the two dropdown lists.

_For example, if Adventure and Leisure is checked, Adventure should be selected on first dropdown and Leisure should be selected on second dropdown._ Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER**

Check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3hdbgw79/5/). It works!

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var i=1;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    $('select#list'+i).val($(this).val());
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 1) {
      $('select#list1').val($(this).val());
    } else {
      $('select#list2').val($(this).val());
    }
  }else{
    $('select#list1').val($('select#list2').val())
    $('select#list2').val('')
  }
});
```

if you don't want if else condition we can use Conditional (Ternary) Operator.

Comment: Good option.. but you need to work on it more.. Try editing that fiddle with your code..

Comment: @AbhayNikam Thanks for the solution. I am unable to figure it out though. Can you please update your code on my fiddle?

Comment: @AbhayNikam This is the closest I have gotten to make this functional. There is a slight problem though. Let's say a user selects Nature and Culture. Then unselects Nature and chooses Adventure. The dropdown will still show Nature and Adventure instead of Culture and Adventure.

Comment: @AbhayNikam Had a friend fix this for me. It uses a Submit button and then dynamically changes the dropdown list data. Thanks for the help. http://jsfiddle.net/3hdbgw79/5/